# ScalaTest and Mockito - unresolved dependency

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, mockito, scalatest

I am trying the add the **mockito** dependency in the SBT build file, But it gives below unresolved dependency exception.

I am not sure if its the issue with Scala and Mockito version.

```
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.2" % "test",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5" % "test")
```

Exception :

```
trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.mockito#mockito-all;1.9.5: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.mockito#mockito-all;1.9.5: not found
[error] Total time: 23 s, completed Oct 12, 2017 3:13:16 PM
```

I have tried with different mockito version 1.8.5 as well. But no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly advise not to use mockito-all with sbt, but use mockito-core instead. SBT is smart build system and it will figure out all dependencies for mockito-core, [details](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Declaring-mockito-dependency). Here how your dependencies might look:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.8.47" % "test"
)
```

Comment: I did changed the dependency versions to aforementioned. But still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: Don't you have any problem with proxy and network configuration? Are you able to get the listing of the folder https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/ ?

Comment: Nope, i don't see any folder created for mockito. I have tried with different mockito versions as well, But its failing with the same error message.

Comment: Issue resolved, As you had pointed out,  it was the issue with network. I tried connecting to a different network and now i am able to load the dependencies. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The [Mockito documentation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#please-ensure-you-dont-declare-mockito-core-as-a-dependency-mockito-scala-will-pull-the-appropiate-version-automatically) advises to not use mockito-core as a dependency, but to use mockito-scala which will pull what's needed. You could use the %% notation which automatically pulls the version appropriate for the Scala version you are using. It's also worth looking on [Maven](https://search.maven.org) to see which is the latest mockito-scala version for the Scala version you are using.

So the build.sbt for Mockito used with Scala with today's latest version would be:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
  "org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.15.0" % "test"
)
```